# Adding a Tag to a NotificationHub in OnRegistered method

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, azure-notificationhub

In my application after successfully login I would like to register to the NotificationHub with a Tag, where Tag is an email address.

The following scenario works fine on iOS:

```
MessagingCenter.Subscribe<LoginViewModel, string>(this, MessagesId.RegisterForPush, (s, arg) =>
            {
                NSSet tags = new NSSet(arg); // create tags if you want
                Hub.RegisterNativeAsync(deviceToken, tags, (errorCallback) =>
                {
                    if (errorCallback != null)
                        Console.WriteLine("RegisterNativeAsync error: " + errorCallback.ToString());
                });
            });
```

but equivalent for Android throws an `NetworkOnMainThreadException`:

```
MessagingCenter.Subscribe<LoginViewModel, string>(this, MessagesId.RegisterForPush, (s, arg) =>
        {
            var tags = new List<string>() { arg };

            try
            {
                var hubRegistration = Hub.Register(registrationId, tags.ToArray());
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Log.Error(PushHandlerBroadcastReceiver.TAG, ex.Message);
            }
        });
```

Do you have any idea how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use a `Task.Run` to get the registration process *off* the main UI thread.

```
await Task.Run(() =>
{
   // your register code here...
});
```

Comment: Yeah thank you, this solved the issue. Now I am having another but it is different thing.

Comment: @AshwiniChougale I think you commented on the wrong answer, this has nothing to do with your problem.

Comment: @SushiHangover  Ok. I got correct way to solve my problem.