# Getting "Android.OS.NetworkOnMainThreadException" exception while UnregisterAll from Azure notification hub.

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

I am getting "Android.OS.NetworkOnMainThreadException: Exception of type 'Android.OS.NetworkOnMainThreadException' was thrown." error while i am unregistering from Azure notification hub.

Comment: Can you share the code that throws this exception?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adding a Tag to a NotificationHub in OnRegistered method](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38589721/adding-a-tag-to-a-notificationhub-in-onregistered-method)

Comment: I linked a dup, different Azure method being used, but same solution.

Comment: I am getting the error while i am Unregistering from hub.

Hub.UnregisterAll(token);